# Spline with multiple durations

Tags: lua, interpolation, equation, spline

I'm trying to make a spline that has multiple durations. Basically, I want to create a spline generated through user supplied key frames. There may be multiple key frames with different durations. So I ask, how would I make a that travels at different speeds through different key frames. Let's say I want there to be 1 second between key frame A and B, but 5 seconds between B and C. Similar to the way animation editors like Source Filmmaker, or Autodesk Maya do it. Every time I've seen someone make a spline, it always has one, constant speed. Always *X* seconds between key frames, but this is not how animation editors work, as they have different speeds, that's what I want.

Just to note, I have tried. I made the duration change once it gets to a different key frame, but that just instantly slows it down, like some slow motion movie effect, which is not what I'm looking for. Do I just gradually transition the speed to fit that of the next key frame? Is there just some equation?

```
function smooth( points, steps ) --points is an array, steps is how many frames inbetween spline points

if #points < 3 then
    return points
end

local steps = steps or 5

local spline = {}
local count = #points - 1
local p0, p1, p2, p3, x, y, z

for i = 1, count do

    if i == 1 then
        p0, p1, p2, p3 = points[i], points[i], points[i + 1], points[i + 2]
    elseif i == count then
        p0, p1, p2, p3 = points[#points - 2], points[#points - 1], points[#points], points[#points]
    else
        p0, p1, p2, p3 = points[i - 1], points[i], points[i + 1], points[i + 2]
    end 

    for t = 0, 1, 1 / steps do

        -- Main spline equation
        x = 1 * ( ( 2 * p1.x ) + ( p2.x - p0.x ) * t + ( 2 * p0.x - 5 * p1.x + 4 * p2.x - p3.x ) * t * t + ( 3 * p1.x - p0.x - 3 * p2.x + p3.x ) * t * t * t )
        y = 1 * ( ( 2 * p1.y ) + ( p2.y - p0.y ) * t + ( 2 * p0.y - 5 * p1.y + 4 * p2.y - p3.y ) * t * t + ( 3 * p1.y - p0.y - 3 * p2.y + p3.y ) * t * t * t )
        z = 1 * ( ( 2 * p1.z ) + ( p2.z - p0.z ) * t + ( 2 * p0.z - 5 * p1.z + 4 * p2.z - p3.z ) * t * t + ( 3 * p1.z - p0.z - 3 * p2.z + p3.z ) * t * t * t )
        if not(#spline > 0 and spline[#spline].x == x and spline[#spline].y == y and spline[#spline].z == z) then
            table.insert( spline , { x = x , y = y, z = z } )               
        end 

    end

end 

return spline

end
```

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: (Sorry for the delays, not a really convenient time) I'm using Lua, but this question isn't that language specific. I just want to know how to do it. Like, do I transition the speed? Is there some equation that solves the speed?

Comment: (Late response, moving is troubling) Well, I'm having trouble understanding what you mean, can you maybe post your response as an answer instead of a comment and make it more detailed?

Comment: Post your code that does everything you need except changing speed.  I'll amend your code.

Comment: I just added the code.

Comment: I want to understand how you would use the spline.  Let's say, you need 1 second between key frame A and B and 5 seconds between B and C.  Which form of output is preferable: "array form" (simple array `spline` with 5 times more points between B and C compared to number of points between A and B) or "function form" for using in `Update()`-like events (a function gets current time and returns x, y, z) ?

Comment: Well, I put an array of points into the function. The function then returns an array of all of the frames of the spline. So yes, "array form" is preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straightforward approach was used:

```
local zero_vector = {0, 0, 0}

local function get_slope(is_edge, left, right)
   if is_edge then
      return zero_vector
   else
      local t = right.time - left.time
      assert(t > 0, "Non-increasing time sequence")
      return {(right[1] - left[1])/t, 
              (right[2] - left[2])/t, 
              (right[3] - left[3])/t}
   end
end

function smooth(checkpoints, frames_per_second)
   frames_per_second = frames_per_second or 5
   if #checkpoints < 2 then
      return checkpoints
   end
   -- Prepare formulas for each segment of spline
   local formulas = {}
   for segment = 1, #checkpoints - 1 do
      local left = checkpoints[segment]
      local right = checkpoints[segment + 1]
      local t = right.time - left.time
      assert(t > 0, "Non-increasing time sequence")
      local left_deriv = get_slope(segment == 1, 
         checkpoints[segment - 1], right)
      local right_deriv = get_slope(segment == #checkpoints - 1, 
         left, checkpoints[segment + 2])
      formulas[segment] = {}
      for j = 1, 3 do
         local d = left[j]
         local c = left_deriv[j]
         local a = (right[j] - d - c*t) / (t*t)
         local b = 3*a + (c - right_deriv[j])/t
         formulas[segment][j] = {(a - b)/t, b, c, d}
      end
   end
   -- Calculate spline points
   local total_seconds = checkpoints[#checkpoints].time - checkpoints[1].time
   local segment = 1
   local spline = {}
   for frame_no = 0, total_seconds * frames_per_second do
      local t = checkpoints[1].time + frame_no / frames_per_second
      local point = {time = t}
      while segment < #formulas and t > checkpoints[segment + 1].time do
         segment = segment + 1
      end
      t = t - checkpoints[segment].time
      for j = 1, 3 do
         local c = formulas[segment][j]
         point[j] = ((c[1]*t + c[2])*t + c[3])*t + c[4]
      end
      table.insert(spline, point)
   end
   return spline
end
```

Usage example:

```
--                     x   y   z  "timestamp in seconds"
local checkpoint_A = {11, 12, 13, time = 0}
local checkpoint_B = {21, 15, 18, time = 1}  -- 1 second  between A and B
local checkpoint_C = {13, 24, 20, time = 6}  -- 5 seconds between B and C

local checkpoints = {checkpoint_A, checkpoint_B, checkpoint_C}

-- total duration is 6 seconds, 10 frames per second, 61 points returned
local array_of_61_points = smooth(checkpoints, 10)

for _, point in ipairs(array_of_61_points) do
   print(string.format("time = %.1f,  x = %.3f,  y = %.3f,  z = %.3f",
      point.time, point[1], point[2], point[3]))
end
```